# How to make two colums grid from this code -Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to make this look side by side (two-column grid). Though I follow the tutorials in Bootstrap is not working for me.

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 section__resume resume-list">
        <h3 class="resume-list_title">education</h3>
        <div class="resume-list__block">
          <p class="resume-list__block-title">University of Minnesota Twin Cities </p>
          <p class="resume-list__block-date">2006 - 2010</p>
          <p>
            Bachelor Computer Engineering Lorem
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="resume-list__block">
          <p class="resume-list__block-title">School of Informational technologies</p>
          <p class="resume-list__block-date">2004 - 2005</p>
          <p>
            Awesome student, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eius-
            mod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="resume-list__block">
          <p class="resume-list__block-title">Lorem Ipsum School</p>
          <p class="resume-list__block-date">2003 - 2006</p>
          <p>
            Student, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte tur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify what do you want to be "side by side"? Which content should be on the left and which on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is based on a 12 column layout. Columns live inside rows. Currently you have a row and the first div in there has the class `col-md-8` this is saying this section of content should take up 8 of the 12 rows on a medium size (or larger unless specified) screen. So on the next div at the same level as that div should have another `col-md-4` and I say 4 so that you use all of the 12 columns allotted by bootstrap. If you want the 2 sections of content to be equal you should make them both have the class of `col-md-6`

Below should be a good starting point and then putting what you want inside the respective rows should get you going on the right path!

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    This is the left half column
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    This is the right half column
  </div>
</div>
```